# Javascript referenced inside the SharePoint 2013 master page is not firing

Tags: 2013

I have a javascript code added inside the SP 2013 master page (OSLO.master), which checks for the anchor tag with the specific class name and changes the href attribute.

The issue is the script is not firing in all the pages, it fires only in those pages where the browser is completely reloaded.

for eg: if you are in homepage, on click of Site contents only the content area gets changed and not the entire page is reloaded(onHashchange concept is being used).

Just wondering how can i make sure that my javascript is executed in all the pages across the site collection.

Note: added the javascript just above  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Team;
var href;
$(document).ready(function() { 
if(window.location.search.indexOf('Team') > -1)
{
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
Team = JSRequest.QueryString["Team"];
var options = {
html: document.getElementById('WelcomePopup'),
width: 500,
height: 400,
showClose: false
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js','SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
});
$("a").mouseover(function() {
href = $(this).attr("href");
var Link = href+"?Team="+Team;
$(this).attr("href",Link);
});
$("a").mouseout(function() {
$(this).attr("href",href);
href='';
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you show us some code? in particular the javascript inclusion and the script

Comment: Edited the post to include the code that i'm currently using...

Comment: what's developer tools saying? i would do a simple alert to ensure the JS is running.

Comment: The developer tool shows the code is loading, but as i mentioned in the question when i click on any link in the page and if the browser is loaded again to render the content the code is firing, else, it is not.Doing a bit of analysis showed me that the hashchange idea is used to change the URL in browser and Onreadystatechange of XML request is used the render the content of destination URL, which means the browser will not be refreshed to load the content of destination URL, because of which i assume the code is not firing in all the pages.

Comment: Any idea how to eliminate this so that the code fires in all the pages

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind the 'hashchange' event and use setTimeOut.
I've added your mouseover and mouseout event. Do you really want to change href for all the anchor tags? If so, make sure you handle all the scenarios such as if href contains '?' then URL should be appended by '&Temp' and such.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match ? decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : null;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var Team = getParameterByName('Team');
    var href;

    if (document.URL.indexOf('Temp') != -1) {
        $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("a").mouseover(function () {
                    href = $(this).attr("href");
                    var Link = href + "?Team=" + Team;
                    $(this).attr("href", Link);
                });
                $("a").mouseout(function () {
                    $(this).attr("href", href);
                    href = '';
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to get it done...Used the same 'hashchange' event to achieve this...if i had got this answer earlier that would have saved much of my time.Hope it will be helpful for someone.Anyways thanks for effort...

Answer (score 0):

Resolution : Finally managed to get the solution.As i mentioned earlier the hashchange event is used to change the url and load the content.Hence, the page will not be reloaded to render the destination url content.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashChange, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onhashchange", hashchange);.

    }
    function hashchange()
    {
    //Code goes here
    }
</script>
```

Hope someone finds it helpful !!!